# Upida .net gives error when I am trying to filter a class which has nested class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, dto, castle-activerecord

I am using Upida for generating DTO from business models. I have also used Castle active as the ORM built on top of nHibernate.

Here is my class which i am trying to filter based on Upida Dto levels:

```
  namespace Web.Models
  {
   [ActiveRecord(Table = TableNames.USER)]
   public class User : DBEntity<User>
   {
    public User()
    {
        MappedUsersandDepartments = new List<UserDepartmentRoleMap>();
    }

    [Dto(DTOLevel.DTO)]
    [Property(Length = 255)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Dto(DTOLevel.DTO)]
    [Property(Length = 255)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Dto(DTOLevel.NOTEXPOSED)]
    [Nested]
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And the nested class is as follows:

```
  namespace Web.Models.Nested
  {
   public class Contact
   {
    [Dto(DTOLevel.DTO)]
    [Property]
    public string LandLine1 { get; set; }

    [Dto(DTOLevel.DTO)]
    [Property]
    public string LandLine2 { get; set; }

    [Dto(DTOLevel.DTO)]
    [Property]
    public string Mobile1 { get; set; }
   }
  }
```

This Contact class is not mapped to a different table in database. It's in the same table USER.
The error I am getting is

```
    Unable to find parser for property: contact, of type: Web.Models.Nested.Contact.
    You must setup custom parser for this property in the Dto attribute.
```

Can anyone help me point out what i am dong wrong or how should i deal with it??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What version of upida do you use ?
This probably happens because the Contact class does not inherit from Upida.Dtobase.